# What database schema and services can be used on GAE with django for free?

Tags: django, database, google-app-engine, web-applications, cloud

We are working on a student cloud app project, hence looking for a free option. Using Google app engine is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all Google App Engine apps are free until you make them "paid apps". You can have up to 10 free apps per account. Wether you use Django or not, doesn't matter how free quotas are applied.

Most of the free quota rules relate to a period of 24 hours. Some quotas are different from this rule, in particular those that are in place because of technical limitations. If free quota of a resource or service is depleted, using this resource or service will throw a server error. Free quotas are replenished after the given period has passed (typically every 24 hours).

Original docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en